# after not appearing when hiding bg_img to img

Tags: css

While using `@media queries`, I'm currently using `uk-hidden@m` for my `img {}` class and use my `bg_img {}`class with `uk-visible@m`.
and this is what they look like:

> (bg_img uk-visible@m)

```
.bg-image {
   position: relative;
   height: ~px;
   width: ~px;
   box-shadow: 10px 11px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
   &::after {
       position: absolute;
       content: '';
       bottom: -46px;
       left: 0;
       height: 46px;
       width: 80%
       background-color: #DCCA7E;
       z-index: -1;
   }
   @include breakpoint(small down) {
       height: 46.72;
   }
}
```

> (img uk-hidden@m)

```
img {
    &::before {
       position: absolute;
       content: '';
       bottom: -46px;
       left: 0;
       height: 46px;
       width: 80%;
       background-color: #DCCA7E;
       z-index: -1;
   }
   @include breakpoint(medium down) {
       max-width: 140%;
   }
}
```

my `&::after` doesn´t show up at media screens before medium, size where `img{}` hides and `bg_img {}` appears. I want to understand WHY this happens, to prevent this in the future.

Appreciate for those taking the time! :)

Comment: Images don't support `::before` ([Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before)): "The pseudo-elements generated by ::before and ::after are contained by the element's formatting box, and thus don't apply to replaced elements such as <img>, or to <br> elements."

Comment: "While using @media queries" your question code does not reference that at all. Please add focus and clarity with a working example that reproduces your issue, the desired output and where you have challenges with it

Comment: honestly, I'm so new I wouldn't know how to display that here. but I'll try:
my php shows that one is replaced by the other when a certain viewport is recognized, thus, using UIkit we display it as: "uk-hidden@m", and "uk-visible@m" for img and bg-img, respectfully. while in the code I just wish to display a color box using pseudo-element `&::after`. not sure if I can explain it further.